# Regular expression with csv not finding blank space

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse a csv file.  I got the following regular expression from google.  It works pretty good except I have one issue and that it doesnt parse blank data.

```
let arrItem = row.match(/(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
arrItem = arrItem || [];
```

Example row data

```
9598,"HERE IS LOOKING AT YOU KID, LLC",85647 GOLDEN BLAH BLAH,,ASHBURN,VA,20147,USA,555-555-1511,45-1111111,SOME@GMAIL.COM,9598,,
```

Here is a screenshot of the arrItem:

[image]

I modified the data in the sample and covered it in the screenshot for privacy.

The problem is that in the array, the third item should be blank and then the 4th should be "Ashburn" and so forth.  Any ideas on how to fix the expression?

I created the following [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wZp5re/1/) 
Thanks

Comment: I would use a csv library written for your language. csv is simple in theory and gets complicated in the fine details. (Not what you're asking, I know.)

Comment: My only idea is to make your regex look for two consecutive commas. I guess you'd have to use lookahead or lookbehind. But yeah, like @Mort says, csv is tricky, especially when using regex alone. Good luck with it.

Comment: Mort, your right.  I just used the npm module csv-parser with very little fuss and it works.